# Does the following define a point of the modular curve $X_1(n)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces, modular-forms

Let $X$ be a compact connected Riemann surface of genus $1$ and suppose that there is a finite morphism $X\to \mathbf{P}^1$ of degree $n$ which ramifies totally over $0$ and $\infty$. Let $f^{-1}(0)$ be the "origin".

**Q.** Is the point $f^{-1}(\infty)$ of order $n$?

If yes, do I understand correctly that the elliptic curve $E=(X,f^{-1}(0))$ with the point $f^{-1}(\infty)$ defines a point on the modular curve $X_1(n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O$ be the preimage of $0$, and let $P$ be the preimage of $\infty$.
Then your hypothesis is that $\text{div}(f) = n(P - O)$, and hence that, indeed,
$P$ is a point of order $n$ on $X$ when you take $O$ to be the origin.

Thus $(X,P)$ does define a point on $X_1(n)$.